# Contact Image from XMPP in android

Tags: android

I am working on XMPP chat client application.I need to know how to display userimage in contact screen. I am able to display Contact name using(getUser()), Status using (getStatus()) in xmpp android. How can i get the user image along with the contact name and status. Is there any function like others in xmpp that is used to display Contact image. Please help me in guiding how to get the contact image with Contact name and Status.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how to get all friend info

```
Roster roster = XMPPConnection.getRoster();
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries= roster.getEntries();
            ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp",
                    new VCardProvider());
            VCard card = null;
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                card = new VCard();
                Presence presencek= roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
                try {
                    card.load(Main.conn, entry.getUser());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String jid = entry.getUser();
                 String name = card.getField("FN");
                String status = presencek.getType().name();
                Log.d("Prescence", "" + presencek.getType().name());// //num one log

                byte[] imgs = card.getAvatar();
                if (imgs != null) {
                    int len = imgs.length;
                    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgs, 0, len);
                }
```

Hope this help anybody :)

Comment: i am using this code able to get name, id, status. but i am getting V-Card not available exception for contact's, i want to get the full status i.e Busy, Idle, Available, Unavailable. Now i am getting available and unavailable. i want remaining things also how can i get those.

Answer (score 0):

I just Got it worked when i changed my code here

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp",
                    new VCardProvider());
```

to

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp:x:update",
                    new VCardProvider());
```